# How do I copy output of a command to a file?

Tags: python, linux

This is the part of long code.

```
ExecutableName = 'op.test'
InterfaceName = 'TN3270'
command = ('./'+ExecutableName+' '+InterfaceName+' 2>&1 | tee -a  filename.txt')
os.system(command)
print command
```

In the end, commands execute properly but output shows on terminal, instead of copying that on "filename.txt" and file is blank. I even try

`command = ('./'+ExecutableName+' '+InterfaceName+' > filename.txt')` and

```
command = ('./'+ExecutableName+' '+InterfaceName+' 2>&1 > filename.txt')
```

But the print statement return same:

```
./op.test TN3270
2>&1 | tee -a  filename.txt
```

I don't know why the output comes in 2 lines and filename.txt is blank?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You could do using subprocess.**

Here is an example.

```
#/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('ps -ef >ProcessFile.txt', shell=True)
retval = p.wait()
```